# Change image on keypress and return it back using javascript, and html

Tags: javascript, html, chatbot

I found a script to create chatbot using html and javascript via this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMakWEj5vKQ

However, I'd like to add something here - and that is to change the image once the user pressed enter key from girl.png to something else e.g. a gif image of the girl and to return back the girl.png once it's done saying something.

Can someone walked me thru on how to do this, please?

The full code is here:

```js
var trigger = [
  ["hi","hey","hello"], 
  ["how are you", "how is life", "how are things"],
  ["what are you doing", "what is going on"],
  ["how old are you"],
  ["who are you", "are you human", "are you bot", "are you human or bot"],
  ["who created you", "who made you"],
  ["your name please",  "your name", "may i know your name", "what is your name"],
  ["i love you"],
  ["happy", "good"],
  ["bad", "bored", "tired"],
  ["help me", "tell me story", "tell me joke"],
  ["ah", "yes", "ok", "okay", "nice", "thanks", "thank you"],
  ["bye", "good bye", "goodbye", "see you later"]
];
var reply = [
  ["Hi","Hey","Hello"], 
  ["Fine", "Pretty well", "Fantastic"],
  ["Nothing much", "About to go to sleep", "Can you guest?", "I don't know actually"],
  ["I am 1 day old"],
  ["I am just a bot", "I am a bot. What are you?"],
  ["Kani Veri", "My God"],
  ["I am nameless", "I don't have a name"],
  ["I love you too", "Me too"],
  ["Have you ever felt bad?", "Glad to hear it"],
  ["Why?", "Why? You shouldn't!", "Try watching TV"],
  ["I will", "What about?"],
  ["Tell me a story", "Tell me a joke", "Tell me about yourself", "You are welcome"],
  ["Bye", "Goodbye", "See you later"]
];
var alternative = ["Haha...", "Eh..."];
document.querySelector("#input").addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
  var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if(key === 13){ //Enter button
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = input;
    output(input);
  }
});
function output(input){
  try{
    var product = input + "=" + eval(input);
  } catch(e){
    var text = (input.toLowerCase()).replace(/[^\w\s\d]/gi, ""); //remove all chars except words, space and 
    text = text.replace(/ a /g, " ").replace(/i feel /g, "").replace(/whats/g, "what is").replace(/please /g, "").replace(/ please/g, "");
    if(compare(trigger, reply, text)){
      var product = compare(trigger, reply, text);
    } else {
      var product = alternative[Math.floor(Math.random()*alternative.length)];
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("chatbot").innerHTML = product;
  speak(product);
  document.getElementById("input").value = ""; //clear input value
}
function compare(arr, array, string){
  var item;
  for(var x=0; x<arr.length; x++){
    for(var y=0; y<array.length; y++){
      if(arr[x][y] == string){
        items = array[x];
        item =  items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
      }
    }
  }
  return item;
}
function speak(string){
  var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
  utterance.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice){return voice.name == "Agnes";})[0];
  utterance.text = string;
  utterance.lang = "en-US";
  utterance.volume = 1; //0-1 interval
  utterance.rate = 1;
  utterance.pitch = 2; //0-2 interval
  speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
}
```

```css
body { 
  color: #421; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; background: #EE4; 
  background-image: url("girl.png"); background-repeat: repeat-y; 
}
span { 
  color: #711; 
} 
::-webkit-input-placeholder { 
  color: #711 
}
#main { 
  position: fixed; top: 40%; right: 60px; width: 400px; 
  border: 0px solid #421; padding: 40px; 
}
#main div { 
  margin: 10px; 
} 
#input { 
  border: 0; background: #EBE547; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid #421; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div>user: <span id="user"></span></div>
  <div>chatbot: <span id="chatbot"></span></div>
  <div><input id="input" type="text" placeholder="say anything..." autocomplete="off"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems there are no time gap between pressing enter and showing the result, how to show the image?

Comment: Honestly, I'm new in using javascript and I'm not really sure how to go about the result i'd like to happen. If someone can at least show me a code or point me to the right direction to achieve it, would greatly appreciate it.